# Не работает авторизация ipv6 проксей

Tags: proxy, vps, прокси, ipv6

В чем ошибка? Прописал (user, pass), но при заходе с браузера, не авторизуется и беспрерывно выскакивает форма для авторизации. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#--------------3proxy.cfg-----------
# ВНИМАНИЕ! Не должно быть пробелов
# перед любыми опциями конфигурации.
#-------------3proxy.cfg------------
#----------Краткая справка----------
# auth none   - Отсутствие какой-либо авторизации. Списки доступа не проверяются.
# auth iponly - Будет идти проверка по списку доступа с использованием IP клиента, IP и номера порта назначения.
# auth strong - Проверяется имя и пароль.
#-----------------------------------
# Важно указать данное значение, так как только при нем процесс 3proxy уйдет в background
daemon
# Записывать pid текущего процесса в файл
pidfile /usr/local/3proxy/3proxy.pid
# IP адреса
# тот IP, который необходимо слушать
internal 0.0.0.0
# тот IP, через который ходить во внешний мир
external 0.0.0.0
#DNS серверы провайдера, или из /etc/resolv.conf
nserver 79.140.28.1
nserver 79.140.28.5
# Оставьте размер кэша для запросов DNS по умолчанию
nscache 65536
# таймауты
timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
# логи работы
# путь к файлу логов
log /usr/local/3proxy/logs/3proxy.log D
# формат логов
logformat "L%C - %U [%d/%o/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z] ""%T"" %E %I %O %N/%R:%r"
# сжимать логи при помощи gzip
archiver gz /usr/bin/gzip %F
# хранить логи 30 дней
rotate 30
# Пользователи
users vik:CL:pass
# Конфигурация http(s) proxy
# включаем авторизацию по логинам и паролям
auth strong
# ограничим доступ по портам через http(s)-proxy
#allow * * * 80-88,8080-8088 HTTP
#allow * * * 443,8443 HTTPS
#allow user1,user2 192.168.1.4,95.95.95.95 * * *
allow vik
deny *
# запустим web прокси на порту 5190
proxy -p5190
# очищаем список access-листов которые остались от http-proxy
flush
# Конфигурация socks5-proxy
# включаем авторизацию по логинам и паролям
auth strong
# ограничим доступ по портам через ocks5-proxy
allow vik
deny *
# запускаем socks
socks -p5222
# очищаем список access-листов которые остались от socks-proxy
flush
# принимать запросы ICQ с 5180 порта
auth none
icqpr -t 5180 login.icq.com 5190
# очищаем список access-листов
flush
# Админский доступ
auth strong
allow vik
maxconn 3
admin -p31338
# очищаем список access-листов
flush
# запускаем сервер от пользователя nobody
setgid 65534
setuid 65534
##-----------------------------------
```

Так же Debian чувствителен к пробелам, может стоит вместо "пробелов" использовать "Tab"